# Using result of SELECT to use in FROM clause

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have this basic table:

```
CREATE TABLE default.myTable
(
    MyUrl String
)
ENGINE = Log
```

Some examples values

```
Insert into myTable('https://www.google.com/?hl=en');
Insert into myTable('https://www.bing.com/?setlang=en');
```

And I want for each value in  ***MyUrl*** field results use inside FROM function

**Result desired**

```
SELECT
    extractTextFromHTML(html) as text,html
FROM
    url(MyUrl,RawBLOB,'html String')
```

| text | html |
| --- | --- |
| Google Search Images Maps Play Yo... | <!doctype html><html itemscop ... |
| Bing Images Videos Videos Maps MSN Office Outlook | <!doctype html><meta name=" |

Is this possible?

Comment: I've not used `clickhouse`. What does `SELECT * FROM url(MyURL, RawBLOB, 'html string')` return? Can you share a sample? I'm thinking that since `url` returns a table then that table's columns should be referenceable in the `extractTextFromHTML()` function. I'm sure there is some nuance to `clickhouse` that I'm overlooking, but it feels like the right starting point.

Comment: Hllo JNevill, you can view [documentation from url function](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/table-functions/url/#url)

Comment: It's impossible. url function accepts only constant URLs

Comment: Thanks @DennyCrane ! I'll have use python script or command line bu it seems less awesome  :p